# How to convert UTF16LE CSV file to UTF8 without losing Commas

Tags: powershell, csv, utf-8, character-encoding

We receive Cognos reports that are encoded as UTF16LE.  I am trying to create a powershell script to convert the UTF16LE files to UTF8.  My logic so far does loop through the directory (whichever directory I place the script in as hardcoding the directory names that contain date/numbers caused errors) and save the files as UTF-8; however, the delimiters seem to be removed.

I believe that it may be due to the way that I am reading the data, as I am not specifying UTF16LE; however, I am unsure of any way to do that.   My script so far is:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem 
$dt = get-date -Format yyyyMMdd
$extension = "_" + "$dt" + "_utf8.csv"
ForEach ($file in $files) {
  $file_name = $file.basename
  $new_file = "$file_name" + "$extension"
  echo $new_file
  #Get-Content $file | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 $new_file
}

Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to Close Window"
```

Any and all insight into this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

PowerShell's [`Import-CSV`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-6) and [`Export-CSV`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-6) cmdlets support the `-Encoding` parameter (links to Microsoft Docs), so you could replace your line

```
Get-Content $file | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 $new_file
```

with

```
Import-CSV -Path $File -Encoding Unicode | Export-CSV -Path $New_File -Encoding UTF8
```

(*UTF16LE encoding is what PowerShell calls "Unicode"; UTF16BE is "BigEndianUnicode". The default is UTF8NoBOM, UTF8 without Byte Order Mark.*)

Answer (score 0):

Since all you want to do is convert the character encoding, reading and writing as a string would be the most straightforward. As always, read a text file with the character encoding it was written with:

```
Get-Content -Encoding Unicode $file | Set-Content -Encoding UTF8 $new_file
```

Encoding "Unicode" for UTF-16 harkens back to the infancy of the Unicode character set when UCS-2 was going to be "it" for many environments. Then the explosion happened and UTF-16 was born from UCS-2. Systems invented since then quite reasonably use UTF16 or similar when they mean UTF-16 and "Unicode" for UTF-16 is esoteric and imponderable.